# indentation in a latex tabular

Tags: latex

I would like to know if it is possible to add indentation in a latex tabular.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a [mre] and clarify what should be changed? From the markdown tables it seems you want both columns to be the same width?

Comment: I would like to have a indentation for specific rows in my tabular. The option "add_indent()" of kableExtra allow this, but i want it in a Latex tabular.

Comment: Can you add a [mre] and include a sketch which shows how the result should look like? I don't see how the markdown tables you show have anything to do with indentation ....

Comment: I have had an exemple (link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of indenting text, I would use two columns and merge them for cells which should start at the left:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{Q[0.3cm]l}
\SetCell[c=2]{} Délits & \\
\SetCell[c=2]{} Circulation & \\
\SetCell[c=2]{} dont & \\
& conduit en état alcoolique\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]